# syntax error when running rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am new to ruby and rails, so I am still attempting to get a handle on the syntax and structure of ruby.  I am following [a tutorial](http://dwradcliffe.com/2011/12/29/import-csv.html) to import a csv file using a task and rake. I keep getting a syntax error though. I am not sure what I am missing, I do not see any difference between the example and my code.

```
require 'csv'

    desc "Import Voters from CSV File"

    task :import => [:environment] do

      file ="db/my.csv"

      CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
        Voter.create{
          :last_name => row[0]
        }  

      end






(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Erics-MacBook-Air:cloudvoters ecumbee$ rake db:import --trace
rake aborted!
/Users/ecumbee/Desktop/cloudvoters/lib/tasks/import.rake:11: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
      :last_name => row[0], 
                   ^
/Users/ecumbee/Desktop/cloudvoters/lib/tasks/import.rake:12: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting '='
    }  
     ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the parenthesis which would surround the hash you're giving as a parameter of the create function

```
    Voter.create({
      :last_name => row[0]
    })
```

You can also skip both parenthesis & curly brackets

```
    Voter.create :last_name => row[0]
```

Comment: the tutorial had neither of those. is it a change of syntax or a mistake by the original author? also i am now getting an error on the end statement syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
  end

Comment: @Eric: There is ambiguity with `Voter.create{...}`. Is it a Hash argument or a block? How ambiguity is resolved can vary between Ruby versions so your tutorial is probably just old. I put parentheses on my method calls because I'm tired of this sort of nonsense; most Ruby people will disagree with me on this but I'm a professional heretic so I don't mind.

Comment: @muistooshort i assume its a hash argument. if i understand properly it should be a call to create a new object based on my voter model.

Comment: im still stumped on where the unexpected end is coming from

Answer (score 1):

As @pjam pointed out, you have to use parenthesis before curly braces, or skip both.

For eg.`Voter.create :last_name => row[0]`

The other problem related to `unexpected $end, expecting kEND end` is you have a missing `end`

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import Voters from CSV File"

task :import => [:environment] do

  file ="db/my.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
    Voter.create{
      :last_name => row[0]
    }  

  end
```

You are ending `CSV.foreach` block with the `end` on last line but not ending the `task`
So by adding extra `end` this error will be removed.

Hope this helps.